# How to encrypt a string in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, encryption

I want to be able to encrypt and decrypt a string using a block cipher like AES.

```
var jsn = JSON.stringify(Json);
var encrypted = AesEncrypt(jsn, pass);
saveStringToFile(encrypted, fnm);
```

I want to do this in vanilla JavaScript and without using 3rd party libraries or using 3rd party libraries that are licensed under something like the MIT license. For example, google's CryptoJS is not free for commercial use, and jakubzapletal/crypto-js is licensed under MIT license, but is based on google's CryptoJS, so that can't work for me either.

Comment: whaaaat is wrong with my question now. It is specific, it isn't something that is obvious how to do, and is not a duplicate?

Comment: CryptoJS is free for commercial use. It's licensed under the [BSD 3 Clause license](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause). Also, do you accept answers that use standard Web APIs outside of the EcmaScript spec?

Comment: "I want to do this in vanilla JavaScript and without using 3rd party libraries" - that makes your question off-topic because writing an entire AES library is too broad - "or using 3rd party libraries that are licensed under something like the MIT license." - and this makes it off-topic because, well, external resource requests are off-topic.

Comment: @D. Pradal I want a solution that will work in all major browsers that I can copy/paste or download in a single js file if possible and I can forget about it - that's all.  And I know that if I use someone's implementation from a tutorial or smth it might be flawed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're running the code inside of a Web browser, you can use the [Web Cryptography API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API):

```js
const te = new TextEncoder();

window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
  {
    name: "AES-GCM", // CTR and CBC modes are also available.
    iv // The initialization vector.
  },
  key, // The CryptoKey. You can get one with window.crypto.subtle.importKey().
  te.encode("Hello, World!"); // The data to encrypt
);
```